# Polar coordinates of an egg-shaped curve

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

For a simple 3D-rendering project, I need to get the shape of an egg. (actually, a prism with an egg-shaped based). The idea behind it is to explain how a camshaft in an engine is working.

From [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovo%C3%AFde), I found the implicit definition: `a.(1+k.y).x^2 + b.y^2 = 1`

However, the page is fairly simple and has no english translation which seems to point that I'm missing something.

I need that curve in polar coordinates : I tried using `x=r(theta).cos(theta)` and `y=r(theta).sin(theta)`but I'm slightly rusted and could not solve it. Looking on the internet, I didn't find an obvious answer, so I'm wondering if there is one.

Any idea ? 
The reason why I need polar coordinates is that I need to rotate that egg and have the offset for moving my valve. It seems a very common and simple mechanical question, so I think there is an answer.

If there is none, I'll go back to using parts of cylinders.

I'm not comfortable with the usage of tags on this site, so I probably got it wrong (more of a stack overflow person)

Comment: For a parametric equation you'd better switch to Cassini ovals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval

Comment: Look at this: http://www.osaka-ue.ac.jp/zemi/nishiyama/math2010/egg.pdf

Comment: You can use half a circle and half an ellipse... the equations are easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed a fifferent approach that I described in a blog post: split the shape into parts, then compute the value for each part.

I used the old : split into circles streategy, whbich gives me a C1 surves, which is good enough.

More details in http://www.revelut.ch/2016/02/01/egg-shape-and-camshaft/

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try with something like:
$$
r=k(\cos^2\theta+a\cos\theta+b).
$$
With suitable choices of parameters $a$ and $b$ the resulting curve is acceptably egg-shaped. See here an interactive demonstration: http://tube.geogebra.org/m/2480891 .

Comment: This is a nice result, I couldn't however create the relevant object, so I ended up following a different solution